# Countdown timer not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, setinterval

The countdown timer I created doesn't work.
Interestingly, if I use console.log to print the value of count--which starts at 3--something like -3498 is printed, even if I am only on for around 15 seconds, so there must be something wrong with the set interval code. The value is displayed(if count is greater than 0), but set interval changes too quickly.

Here's the code.

```
function countdown(){
  window_width=window.innerWidth-70;
  window_height=window.innerHeight-150;

  canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width  = window_width;
  canvas.height=window_height;

  if(count>0){
    ctx.font = '40pt Calibri';
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillText(count, window_width/3, window_height/2);
  }
  else if(count===0){
    ctx.fillText("Go!", window_width/3, window_height/2);
  }
  else{
   return;
  }

  setInterval(function(){count=count-1},1000);
  requestAnimationFrame(countdown);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It appears as if `count` may be a global variable, and if so, that is where your problem lies. Your setInterval function is fine. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigbiff02/HPdAX/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit unclear as to what you're trying to accomplish, but here's a shot at it:

```
window.count = 3;

setTimeout(countdown,1000);

function countdown(){
  window_width=window.innerWidth-70;
  window_height=window.innerHeight-150;

  canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width  = window_width;
  canvas.height=window_height;

  count--;

  if(count>0){
    ctx.font = '40pt Calibri';
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillText(count, window_width/3, window_height/2);
    setTimeout(countdown,1000);
  }
  else if(count===0){
    ctx.fillText("Go!", window_width/3, window_height/2);
  }
  else{
   return;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(countdown); // not sure if this is needed
}
```

As far as I can tell, you don't need the interval.

Comment: You're welcome :) If this answer solved your problem, you may want to accept it and/or vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

> The value is displayed, but changes too quickly

You will need to distinguish between logic and presentation. When the `countdown` function is called, you schedule a function to decrease the count in 1s, and at the same time you schedule `countdown` to be called again as fast as possible. The update interval of canvases is about 16ms though… It means the `count` is decreased at that rate, only delayed 1 second after starting.

And it's even worse, as you did use `setInterval` which forever repeats decreasing the `count`, while that process is started every animation frame…

The solution is not to use `setTimeout`/`setInterval` at all. They are unreliable and should not be used for measuring the time. Instead, get accurate timestamps from the [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) (every time you need them, ie. every animation frame):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width  = window.innerWidth -70;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight-150;
ctx.font = '40pt Calibri';
ctx.fillStyle = "white";

var count = …;

var estimatedEnd = Date.now() + count*1000;

function countdown(){
    var currentCount = (estimatedEnd - Date.now()) / 1000;

    if (currentCount>0){
        ctx.fillText(currentCount, window_width/3, window_height/2);
        requestAnimationFrame(countdown);
    } else if (currentCount===0){
        ctx.fillText("Go!", window_width/3, window_height/2);
    }
}
countdown();
```

Comment: `Date.now()` it's not the best for cross-browser since older browsers doesn't implement it. Suggestion is replace `Date.now()` by `new Date().getTime()` to ensure compatibility with older browsers.

Comment: Sure, but as you say it's really easy to shim if one needs to support outdated browsers… And you can expect that browsers which support canvas and requestAnimationFrame will support `Date.now` as well :-)

Comment: Completely right! My point will be true only if some requestAnimationFrame polyfill (with setInterval or setTimeout fallback) was triggered, because there are browsers that support canvas but not requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: My main method of marketing is the Chrome web store though, so nearly everyone will be running on Chrome.

Comment: I would normally use this method, but it does not need to be  particularly accurate in my case. Check out the end result [here](http://asteroidfield.eu5.org).